# how to connect custom onmessage handler with Strophe

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, strophe

I am working with Strophe on a facebook chat system, so far, the login and sending messages works.

So far I can see in the Google Chrome Inspector console that the incoming messages are registered, however, I currently dont have any incoming message handlers registered.

I've tried

```
conn.addHandler(AjaxIM.client.incoming, null, "chat");

-- and --

conn.addHandler(AjaxIM.client.incoming, null, "message", null, null, null);
```

But that didn't seem to do anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
conn.addHandler(handler, null, 'message', 'chat');
```

See the fine [docs](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.0.2/files2/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.addHandler) ;)

Comment: I actually had a look at them, however I couldnt find information about valid Name and Type values ;)

Comment: @xorinzor 'name' is the kind of stanza, i.e. 'message', 'presence' or 'iq'. The 'type' matches the 'type' attribute of the stanza, which depends on the kind of stanza. For messages see http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#message-syntax-type